# Styling Xfce Applications Menu with gtkrc

Tags: xfce

I'm a bit stumped. I'm using Xfce 4.10.1 in Xubuntu 14.04. The old Applications Menu is better for my workflow than the new Whisker Menu but I'm having trouble increasing the icon size in it from the default 16px to 24px.

In Xfce 4.10.0, I simply had to add a line to HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xsettings.xml. According to Xfce Docs, that function is now taken over by the gtkrc theme file:

```
XfceApplicationsMenuPlugin
-----------------------------
You can set a custom icon size in gtk-icon-sizes with the name
panel-applications-menu. The default icon size is 16px.
Special widget name in this plugin is applicationmenu-button.
```

Source of the above here: https://github.com/EasternHeart/heartlenv-shell/blob/master/docs/README.gtkrc-2.0

There's no example there so I have tried variants of the following with no success:

```
style "panel-applications-menu"

    { 
        gtk-icon-sizes = "panel-applications-menu = 24,24"
    }
class "XfceApplicationsMenuPlugin"  style "panel-applications-menu"
widget "applicationmenu-button" style "panel-applications-menu"
```

I've also tried adding the above to &Home/.gtkrc-2.0 without success.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running xfce 4.12 but this might work on 4.10 too.
Try copying a theme (eg. Bluebird) from `/usr/share/themes/Bluebird` to `~/.themes/Bluebird-custom` then edit `~/.themes/Bluebird-custom/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

The code order is important, so add this at the very end

```
style "applicationsmenu" {
  xthickness = 0
  ythickness = 0
}
widget "*applicationsmenu*" style "applicationsmenu"
```

I got the widget name (applicationsmenu) by right-clicking the panel then going `panel > panel preferences > items` and hovering the mouse over an item to display a tooltip with its "internal name".

Comment: Oh, now I see... you want to style the ApplicationMenu's menu icons, not the ApplicationMenu's icon. My bad. Please disregard my answer.